# Is there a public issue tracking for Stack Overflow?

Tags: support

I want to propose some improvements, but I can't find an issue tracking website for Stack Overflow.

Comment: An interesting improvement could be a link to the other question...

Comment: What other question? The duplicate? The link is right there in the yellow box.

Comment: Male sure to go over the existing improvements: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/feature-request

Comment: You can propose them here on Meta (after checking for duplicates) but don't hold your breath on anything happening.